# Using lapply to transpose part of a column and add it as new columns to a data frame

Tags: r

I've been searching for some clarity on this one, but cannot find something that applies to my case, I constructed a DF very similar to this one (but with considerably more data, over a million rows in total)

```
Key1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C") 
Key2 <- c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "C2", "B2", "B3", "C3", "A3", "C4") 
NumVal <- c(2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 1, 0)
DF1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Key1, Key2, NumVal), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% arrange(Key2)
ConsId <- c(1:10)
DF1 <- cbind(DF1, ConsId)
```

Now, what I want to do is to add lets say 3 new columns (in real life I need 12, but in order to be more graphic in this toy example we'll use 3) to the data frame, where each row corresponds to the values of $NumVal with the same $Key1 and greater than or equal $ConsId to the ones in each row and filling the remaining spaces with NA's, here is the expected result in case I wasn't very clear:

```
Key1    Key2    NumVal  ConsId  V1  V2  V3
A        A1        2       1    2   4   1
A        A2        4       2    4   1   NA
A        A3        1       3    1   NA  NA
B        B1        3       4    3   8   2
B        B2        8       5    8   2   NA
B        B3        2       6    2   NA  NA
C        C1        1       7    1   6   3
C        C2        6       8    6   3   0
C        C3        3       9    3   0   NA
C        C4        0      10    0   NA  NA
```

Now I'm using a do.call(rbind), and even tough it works fine, it takes way too long for my real data with a bit over 1 million rows (around 6 hrs), I also tried with the bind_rows dplyr function but it took a bit longer so I stuck with the do.call option, here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
# Function
TranspNumVal <- function(i){
  Id <- DF1[i, "Key1"]
  IdCons <- DF1[i, "ConsId"]
  myvect <- as.matrix(filter(DF1, Id == Key1, ConsId >= IdCons) %>% select(NumVal))
  Result <-  as.data.frame(t(myvect[1:3]))
  return(Result)
}

# Applying the function to the entire data frame
DF2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NROW(DF1), function(i) TranspNumVal(i)))
DF3 <- cbind(DF1, DF2)
```

Maybe changing the class is causing the code to be so inefficient, or maybe I'm just not finding a better way to vectorize my problem (you don't want to know how long it took with a nested loop), I'm fairly new to R and have just started fooling around with dplyr, so I'm open to any suggestion about how to optimize my code

Comment: Don't use `as.data.frame(cbind` as it creates a matrix first and then a data.frame and it will have problems in the type.  Just do `data.frame(Key1, Key2, ..`

Comment: What happens when you have more than three rows per `Key1` like in the case of `Key1 = C`? The new columns in the first row for `Key1 = C` cannot store all `NumVal` values. In that case do you only keep the first three?

Comment: Thanks, will take it into consideration for future references

Comment: yes @MauritsEvers we only keep the first 3, I need to drop the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::lead`

```
DF1 %>%
    group_by(Key1) %>%
    mutate(
        V1 = NumVal,
        V2 = lead(NumVal, n = 1),
        V3 = lead(NumVal, n = 2))
## A tibble: 10 x 7
## Groups:   Key1 [3]
#   Key1  Key2  NumVal ConsId V1    V2    V3
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     A1    2           1 2     4     1
# 2 A     A2    4           2 4     1     NA
# 3 A     A3    1           3 1     NA    NA
# 4 B     B1    3           4 3     8     2
# 5 B     B2    8           5 8     2     NA
# 6 B     B3    2           6 2     NA    NA
# 7 C     C1    1           7 1     6     3
# 8 C     C2    6           8 6     3     0
# 9 C     C3    3           9 3     0     NA
#10 C     C4    0          10 0     NA    NA
```

Explanation: We group entries by `Key1` and then use `lead` to shift `NumVal` values for columns `V2` and `V3`. `V1` is simply a copy of `NumVal`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the explanation of how lead works, it solves my problem better than expected

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'Key1', use `shift` (from `data.table`) to get the next value of 'NumVal' in a `list`, convert it to `tibble` and `unnest` the nested `list` elements to individual columns of the dataset.  By default, `shift` `fill` NA at the end.

```
library(data.table) 
library(tidyverse)
DF1 %>% 
  group_by(Key1) %>% 
  mutate(new = shift(NumVal, 0:(n()-1), type = 'lead') %>% 
                     map(~ 
                          as.list(.x) %>%
                          set_names(paste0("V", seq_along(.))) %>% 
                          as_tibble)) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  select(-V4)
# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   Key1 [3]
#   Key1  Key2  NumVal ConsId    V1    V2    V3
#   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     A1         2      1     2     4     1
# 2 A     A2         4      2     4     1    NA
# 3 A     A3         1      3     1    NA    NA
# 4 B     B1         3      4     3     8     2
# 5 B     B2         8      5     8     2    NA
# 6 B     B3         2      6     2    NA    NA
# 7 C     C1         1      7     1     6     3
# 8 C     C2         6      8     6     3     0
# 9 C     C3         3      9     3     0    NA
#10 C     C4         0     10     0    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Key1, Key2, NumVal, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
                       arrange(Key2)
DF1$ConsId <- 1:10
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` pipeline.

First utility function will filter `a` (`NumVal`) based on the values of `b` (`ConsId`):

```
myfunc1 <- function(a,b) {
  n <- length(b)
  lapply(seq_along(b), function(i) a[ b >= b[i] ])
}
```

Second utility function converts a ragged `list` into a `data.frame`. It works with arbitrary number of columns to append, but we've limited it to 3 based on your requirements:

```
myfunc2 <- function(x, ncols = 3) {
  n <- min(ncols, max(lengths(x)))
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, `length<-`, n)))
}
```

Now the pipeline:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Key1) %>%
  mutate(lst = myfunc1(NumVal, ConsId)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_cols(myfunc2(.$lst)) %>%
  select(-lst) %>%
  arrange(Key1, ConsId)
# # A tibble: 10 × 7
#     Key1  Key2 NumVal ConsId    V1    V2    V3
#    <chr> <chr>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1      A    A1      2      1     2     4     1
# 2      A    A2      4      2     4     1    NA
# 3      A    A3      1      3     1    NA    NA
# 4      B    B1      3      4     3     8     2
# 5      B    B2      8      5     8     2    NA
# 6      B    B3      2      6     2    NA    NA
# 7      C    C1      1      7     1     6     3
# 8      C    C2      6      8     6     3     0
# 9      C    C3      3      9     3     0    NA
# 10     C    C4      0     10     0    NA    NA
```